# How can I push another value in the duplicate value of the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I push another value in the duplicate value of the array?

```
const numArr = [0,5,5,5,1,1,0,0,0,3,3,6,6,6];
const colArr = ['red','blue','yellow']
```

Here, I would like to get the following results.

```
const result = [0,'red','red','red','blue','blue',0,0,0,'yellow','yellow','red','red','red'];
```

I did like this, but I don't know how to loop the colArr.

```
const numArr = [0,5,5,5,1,1,0,0,0,3,3,6,6,6];
const colArr = ['red','blue','yellow']

function solution(numArr , colArr) {

  const answer = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {

    const arrElem = numArr[i];

    if(arrElem == 0) {
      answer.push(0);
    } else {
      answer.push("red")
    }
  }
  return answer;
}


console.log(solution(numArr , colArr))
// The results should be like this..
// answer = [0,'red','red','red','blue','blue',0,0,0,'yellow','yellow','red','red','red'];
```

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, which looks like replacing non-zero numbers with `red`, then `blue`, then `yellow`, then `red` (repeating), based on the number being replaced. So, while looping, keep track of the number you replaced. When you replace the next one, increment the colour (or reset it once you've used `yellow`) if it is different. Please remember that you're expected to make an effort to solve your own issue on Stackoverflow _before_ asking for help. All I see is an `if()` statement, which isn't enough. Try to solve this, and if you get stuck, edit your question 

Comment: Thanks, I eddited my question.

Comment: That's a little better, as it shows an attempt, albeit not a really robust or detailed one, but that's neither here nor there. You were lucky that someone was willing to write this for you completely, which won't always be the case on Stackoverflow. Glad you got it working, but just remember that the more you put into SO the more you'll get out of it. Cheers 

Comment: Thank you. You're so sweet.
It's because I'm not good at English. I will write in more detail next time.

Answer (score 1):

If you return into the loop, your array answer won't be fulled.
You cannot modify a constant value. Replace `const` with `var`

```
var numArr = [0, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6];
var colArr = ['red','blue','yellow']


console.log(solution(numArr , colArr));



function solution(numArr , colArr) {

    var answer = [];
    var lastElem = null;
    var lastIndexColor = null;

    for(let i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {

        var arrElem = numArr[i];

        if(arrElem == 0) {
            answer.push(arrElem);
        }
        else{
            if(lastElem == arrElem){
                answer.push(colArr[lastIndexColor % colArr.length]);
            }
            else{
                if(lastIndexColor == null){
                    lastIndexColor = 0;
                    answer.push(colArr[lastIndexColor % colArr.length]);
                }
                else{
                    lastIndexColor++;
                    answer.push(colArr[lastIndexColor % colArr.length]);
                }
            }
        }
        lastElem = arrElem;
    }
    return answer;
}
```